# Best practice to trigger reconcile after updating K8S Operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder, reconcile

We have implemented an Operator for CRD in Kubernetes by Kubebuilder, and it is expected that the tasks this Operator needs to do in "reconcile" will be changed over time (more logic/handling will be appended). e.g.

First release @time t1 -> logic X

Second release @time t2 -> logic X + Y

Third release @time t3 -> logic X + Y + Z

AFAIK, the trigger for reconcile is the change happened on the CR. However, it is quite obvious that the reconcile should be also triggered in above case for all the managed CRs, but seems like this is not mentioned anywhere.

I wonder if there's any handy way to trigger the reconcile for all managed CRs, or if there's any best pratice for doing so.

----------- Update ------------

After adding log and deploy the Controller several times, I realized that this is by default done by the Controller already. It means every deployment will also trigger the reconcile of all the CRs it manages.

Comment: Have you referred to any best practice documents ?

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu I have checked the official docs and some others as well but couldn't find any that describes such scenario.